# What are the other options to use in the nearest neighbor search algorithm in weka?

Tags: weka, knn

What are our other options to use in the nearest neighbour search algorithm in weka rather than `default: weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Weka's documentation page you can see that they have:

```
 weka.core.neighboursearch
 Classes:
 - BallTree
 - CoverTree
 - KDTree
 - LinearNNSearch
 - NearestNeighbourSearch
 - PerformanceStats
 - TreePerformanceStats
```

Check out the documentation for further details: [Package weka.core.neighboursearch](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/neighboursearch/package-summary.html)